# How to include claims only in id_token but not in access_token IdentityServer4

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I'm using Identity Server 4 and Implicit grant type.
I have a SPA which makes authorization request to IS4 with response_type: 'id_token token'.

I have a simple implementation of IProfileService with GetProfileDataAsync method:

```
public virtual Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);

            context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("custom1", "custom1"));

            context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("custom2", "custom2"));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

And it works OK; I receive an access_token and an id_token. But they both contain my custom claims.

How can I include in access_token only "custom1" claim, but in id_token both "custom1" and "custom2" claims?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Ruard van Elburg, I was able to do it.
Correct answer is:

- For the access token: Context.Caller = ClaimsProviderAccessToken
- For the identity token: Context.Caller = ClaimsProviderIdentityToken
- For userinfo endpoint: Context.Caller = UserInfoEndpoint

And code:

```
public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);

        // Add claims to access token
        if (context.Caller == "ClaimsProviderAccessToken")
        {
            context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("custom1", "custom1"));
        }

        // Add identity token claims
        if (context.Caller == "ClaimsProviderIdentityToken")
        {
            context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("custom1", "custom1"));

            context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("custom2", "custom2"));
        }

        // Add userinfo endpoint claims
        if (context.Caller == "UserInfoEndpoint")
        {
            context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("custom1", "custom1"));

            context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("custom2", "custom2"));
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Profile Service is called multiple times with a different context:

- For the *access token*: `Context.Caller = ClaimsProviderAccessToken`
- For the *identity token*: `Context.Caller = UserInfoEndpoint`

For context specific claims you should check the context caller:

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);

    context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("custom1", "custom1"));

    // Add access token claims
    if (Context.Caller == "ClaimsProviderAccessToken")
    {
    }

    // Add identity token claims
    if (Context.Caller == "UserInfoEndpoint")
    {
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("custom2", "custom2"));
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```