# Setting the `acr_values` does not return acr value in `id_token` after authentication

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, acr

I want to send an acr value to Identity Server 4 during the authentication challenge, and have it returned inside the `id_token` on the redirect back after login.

From what I have read online, I got the impression that this is a usual way to use acr values.

There is nothing special IS4 needs to do with this acr value, only return it back, so I can use it on the site using the authentication provider.

I do send it successfully by setting the`context.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues` during the call of the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` callback, and IS4 does get it, but I don't get anything returned inside the `id_token`.

Do I need to do something special for the acr to be included in the `id_token`? Should I add it manually somehow? Any code samples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, you've got a too optimistic impression :)

Up to date this is rather experimental and optional for the implementation by the particular IdPs. According to the [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest): The `acr` Claim is requested as a *Voluntary Claim* by this parameter.

What Identityserver does is the `acr_values` parameter parsing and limited handling.
According to their [docs](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/endpoints/authorize/):

> Allows passing in additional authentication related information
> IdentityServer special cases the following proprietary `acr_values`:
> **idp:name_of_idp** bypasses the login/home realm screen and forwards the user directly to the selected identity provider (if allowed per client configuration)
> **tenant:name_of_tenant** can be used to pass a tenant name to the login UI

You can send as many space separated values as you want the following way:
 `&acr_values=param1:value1 param2:value2 tenant:name_of_tenant idp:name_of_idp` 
and then perform any custom handling on Identityserver side with the following accessor:

```cs
var ctx = _IIdentityServerInteractionService.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
IEnumerable<string> acrs = ctx.AcrValues;
string tenant = ctx.Tenant;
string idp = ctx.IdP;
```

When you like to inform the client that their `acr_values` have been handled, you can add `acr` like any other user claim: 
First add it to the session in Identityserver when calling

```cs
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(identityServerUser, props);
// Where identityServerUser can take additional claims.
```

After that your custom claim is within the `Subject`.
One way to add it to `id_token` is implementing the `IProfileService` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60527219/1426685).

```cs
public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);
    if (context.Caller == "ClaimsProviderIdentityToken")
    {
        var acr = context.Subject.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Type=="acr");
        if(acr != null)
            context.IssuedClaims.Add(acr);
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

An alternative is to add the claim to the `IdentityResources.OpenId` scope in the `GetIdentityResources()` method in startup. `openid` is the only mandatory scope, so the claim will jump into the token with the default `AddRequestedClaims()` implementation.

Comment: Yes, I do this handling on the IS4 side. I get a hold of the ACR value and I can use it, but what I need is to reflect this fact (that the ACR value was handled) in the site that uses the IDP. From what I have seen online, I thought that the ACR should have been included in the `id_token` automatically, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Do you have any ideas on how to denote to the client that the ACR was handled? E.g. set the ACR on the `id_token` manually or set a claim somewhere?

Comment: I have tried the `HttpContext.SignInAsync()` but it didn't seem to pass the claim to the site. Perhaps I am missing the second step that you mention. I will try that.

Comment: Yep. It seems working. Perhaps you should update the answer and I can accept it. Too bad I cannot set the ACRs in the `id_token`, but this way will do too. Thanks. :)